# Excel formula to have 1x quantity every X amount of units

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Our store needs a simple spreadsheet to keep track of stock.

We sell units in bundles. For example, a specific product could have 50 units in 1 bundle. On our store, the product title contains 50x (indicating 50 units in that bundle) but the actual stock count will be 1 (indicating 1 bundle in stock).

How can I use Excel formula's to have 3 columns like below and as the `Individual unit count` is edited, `the stock count (bundles)` is changed automatically taking into account how many units per bundle for that specific product by the formula?

Example (as there's 74 units, there's not enough to create 2 bundles. So only 1 is added to `Stock count (bundles)` by the forumla. However, our store will still keep track of units as in future this value of 74 units may rise to 100 units for example so then the formula will populate 2 for Stock count (bundles):

| Product | Stock count (bundles) | Individual unit count | Units per bundle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 1 | 74 | 50 |
| SKU2 | 6 | 135 | 20 |

Comment: Could it as simple as =ROUNDDOWN(B3/C3,0) or =FLOOR(B3/C3,1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sous2817 said, you can use the `Floor` -or- `Floor.Math` formula or `Rounddown`. Change the [ ] variables to be the cells that match your inputs.

`=FLOOR( [Individual unit count] / [Units per Bundle], 1)`

`=FLOOR.MATH( [Individual unit count] / [Units per Bundle], 1)`

`=ROUNDDOWN( [Individual unit count] / [Units per Bundle], 1)`

This divides the unit count by how many are in a bundle, then rounds it down the the level of significance which we set to an integer 1 for floor so it will always round down to the next lowest 1; similar logic for the rounddown as it will always round down to the next lowest single digit. Feel free to experiment with inputs to confirm the results are as expected, but this should be a set of formulas you can work with for your need.